# Android malware reversing : constant values

Tags: android

I was trying to reverse engineer an Android Malware sample and I find the following sample when decompiling the jar file I obtained by running `dex2jar`.

> ```
>   if (i >= paramBundle.length())
>   {
>     ((TextView)findViewById(2131034112)).setText(((StringBuilder)localObject).toString());
>     return;
>   }
> ```

How can I find the string that `2131034112` refers to?

Answer (score 3):

The jar file produced by `dextojar` should include a class named `R`, which contains subclasses with resource id definitions:

```
public final class R {
...
    public static final class list {
        public static final int filename=0x7f050001;
        public static final int type=0x7f050000;
    }
...
}
```

The (sub)class name, and variable names, correspond to the ids from the resource definitions in the apk file (res/layout/*.xml). In the above example, the R.java was autogenerated from these entries in res/layout/main.xml:

```
 <TextView
   android:id="@+list/type"
   android:layout_width="20dip"
   android:layout_height="20dip"
   android:textSize="16sp"
    />
 <TextView
   android:id="@+list/filename"
   android:layout_width="0dp"    android:layout_weight="1"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:textSize="16sp"
    />
```

So, since `2131034112` equals `0x7F050000`, with my `R.java` and `main.xml`, your code would set the `@+list/type` textview content.